# get date from ranges

Tags: java, calendar

I have some start date. For example 1.02.1995
And I have some finish date. For example 10.02.1995

I want to divide this range by 10(for example) and get dates of this ranges.

Here it will be 1.02.1995, 2.02.1995, 3.02.1995, 4.02.1995, 5.02.1995, 6.02.1995, 7.02.1995, 8.02.1995, 9.02.1995, 10.02.1995.

I know how to count number of days between two dates, but I'm not sure how to convert 
day(will be 5 for 5.01.1990 if start counting from 1.01.1990) to date, by using library.

I'm not interested in writing algorithm by myself.

The best way to do this?

Thanx

Comment: Canned response: use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It is better to tell what is your expected out put

Comment: `I'm not interested in writing algorithm by myself.` then how can others be interested to write that for you?

Comment: Zaheer, I mean that I'm looking for solution by using of libraries

Answer (score 1):

A sample code , replace .... with real values and methods

**Assuming date format as MM/DD/YYYY**

beware cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); is of range month {0-11} while date range is 1-31

```
Calendar start = .... ;
Calendar end = ....;

int startEndMonthDiff = .... ; // the difference in months 

Calendar temp = ; // set to start date

for(int i=0;i<startEndMonthDiff;i++)
{
   // you may store temp in list at each loop
   temp.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
}
```

Comment: this is my understanding of the question , hope i didnt misunderstand anything :P

Comment: I think there must be  temp.add(Calendar.DAY,x); x = (end-start)/10; Thank you!

Comment: @AnuarSharafudinov , just try it in your project , and **depending on what changes you need modify it**
-- I did ( ,1) because its in a loop and as per question it was 1,2,3,...

Answer (score 0):

Jodatime is the simpleist way of doing this using a little function called daysBetween to get the amount of days then add a date to an array for each day
i.e.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
for (int i=0; i < days; i++) {
    LocalDate d = startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
    dates.add(d);
}
```

Comment: @Anuar Sharafudinov says "I know how to count number of days between two dates"

Comment: @SeanF Read the question again. `I know how to count number of days between two dates`

Comment: re-read the question, that was my bad. Edited my answer, provided i made snese of the question better this time.

Comment: There's no LocalDate class in standard java library.

Comment: as the answer states, use joda time, there is a LocalDate class in JodaTime